# How to scroll GNU info pages without unexpectedly jumping to the next node?

Tags: info

Using the <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd> directional  arrow keys to to scroll up and down the page in the GNU `info` pages causes the info page viewer to unexpectedly jump to another node, this is really disorienting.
How can I scroll down through the page and just have the info viewer/pager stop when it gets to the top or the bottom, and then require a separate command to jump to a different node?

Comment: Use [pinfo](http://pinfo.sourceforge.net/) to browse `info` files.  If you're comfortable with Vim and Vim plugins you can also install [ref](https://github.com/thinca/vim-ref) and [ref-info](https://github.com/eiiches/vim-ref-info) and actually have a sane `info` browser.

Comment: @SatoKatsura thanks, yes I installed and tried `pinfo` I like it but it doesn't work for `pinfo info` which is one of the main index pages which I would use to drill down into more specific pages. `pinfo info` just loads loads `man info`. Also I couldn't work out how to jump to the next search match in `pinfo`

Comment: From a quick look, I believe you want `pinfo info-stnd` rather than `pinfo info`.  Other than that however, well, I'm just a fellow `info` hater, so don't expect me to try too hard to defend `pinfo`. :) The `ref-info` thing is pretty decent though.

Comment: @SatoKatsura yes I think `info` pages are really made by and  intended for emacs users. it looks like the [ref-info](https://github.com/eiiches/vim-ref-info) is vim syntax definitions for `info` pages. So is the idea you open info pages in vim - and `ref-info` plugin gives you ability to navigate?

Comment: No.  You first install `ref`, which is a hypertext browser framework.  `ref` comes with browsers for various sources (`man` pages, `perldoc`, `pydoc`, etc.), but not for `info`.  `ref-info` is a plugin for `ref` that adds support for `info`.  Then you add `let g:ref_info_cmd='info --subnodes -o -'` to your vimrc, and browse `info` pages with `:Ref info <page>`.  You'll probably need to spend some time configuring it.  It's a very useful plugin.

Comment: @SatoKatsura thanks! , I just now installed and tested <https://github.com/alx741/vinfo> - it can't jump to nodes. so I installed the `ref` and `ref-info` plugins for vim and it can jump to nodes nicely!. Still has the same problem as pinfo, I can't load the main `info info` page, but I will keep playing and see if I can get it working.

Comment: @SatoKatsura ah, its `:Ref info info-stnd` thanks

Comment: In my experience `vinfo` is not than great.  At some point I patched a number of problems with it, and it was still less than great.  No such problems with `ref-info`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura yes installing `vim-ref-info` immediately has solved every problem I had trying to use `info` pages. Ironically it converts each node to one massive man page format - which is kind of against the whole point of the info pages, but it works , it can be navigated up and down the nodes, everything,. If you want to copy paste your install instructions (from your previous comment) as an answer, I will accept it - its a bit vim centric but it will probably help other people

Comment: The one huge page (well a few large ones actually) is the effect of `let g:ref_info_cmd='info --subnodes -o -'`.  Remove it if you prefer many small pages instead.  The larger pages are a lot easier to search though.  This is the main problem with `ref-info`: search is not as useful as with the original `info`.

Comment: I presume that this question is intended to specify <KBD>↑</KBD> and <KBD>↓</KBD>?  All I currently see are boxes saying 01F 851 and 01F 853.  I suggest this question is using newer Unicode, unnecessarily reducing compatibility, when more compatible options exist.  (For ease, try copying the characters from this comment, and pasting.)

Comment: Info was a pre-html, great idea that never really took off, much easier to traverse html docs, even in emacs

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Posting as an answer, as requested.

Just don't use `info` to browse `info` pages.  There is a standalone `info` browser named [pinfo](http://pinfo.sourceforge.net/), and Emacs has, of course, its own [Info Mode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InfoMode).

If you're using Vim you can also install the [ref](https://github.com/thinca/vim-ref) and [ref-info](https://github.com/eiiches/vim-ref-info) plugins.  `ref` is essentially a generic hypertext browser.  It comes with plugins for a number of sources, such as `man` pages, `perldoc`, `pydoc`, etc., but not for `info`.  `ref-info` is a plugin for `ref` that adds capability to browse `info` pages.

The combination `ref`+`ref-info` makes a decent `info` browser, with the only drawback that it can only search through the page it currently displays.  A partial workaround for this problem is to tell the `info` backend to produce larger chunks before feeding them to `ref-info`, by adding this line to your vimrc:

```
let g:ref_info_cmd = 'info --subnodes -o -'
```

You'd then browse `info` pages like this:

```
:Ref info <page>
```

Of course, you can also use `ref` with the other sources (`:Ref man <page>` etc.).  Read the manual for more information.

Comment: thanks for the great explanation. I agree with the  `let g:ref_info_cmd = 'info --subnodes -o -'` idea of bunching everything into a single page. I always use the `zsh` man pages this way too, i.e. the `zsh` man pages are broken into about 12 separate man pages, but I always load `man zshall` for doing regex searches, then once I know where  the thing I want is, then load the specific man page e.g. `man zshbuiltins`

Answer (score 5):

You can use <kbd>Control-V</kbd> to *scroll-forward-page-only*, and the reverse <kbd>Meta-V</kbd> or <kbd>Escape-V</kbd> for *scroll-backward-page-only*. These are listed in the `h` help page, but they are hard to spot.

Comment: thanks, I could use a half page scroll, like `C-d` in `less`, but scrolling an entire page at a time is a bit disorienting.